# is it bad to hash raw buffer by using std::string as a wrapper?

Tags: c++, c++11

C++ `std::hash<>` [has some standard specializations](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash) for fix-sized basic types, and `std::string` family, which is the only one having variable memory size(and `std::vector<bool>` too, unconcerned here)

once we tend to hashing multiple variables or a buffer, we need to implement a hashing algorithom, which is hard to remember and easily be wrong.

`std::string` can be used as a buffer(`std::vector<std::byte>` is better, I know), and if we store utf-8 string(which have bytes other than ASCII) in it, it is likely hashes well too.

what is the disadvantage like this:

```cpp
std::string hash_wrapper(4 * 4, '\0');
int* write_ptr = reinterpret_cast<int*>(hash_wrapper.data());

write_ptr[0] = val1;
write_ptr[1] = val2;
write_ptr[2] = val3;
write_ptr[3] = val4;

std::unordered_map<std::string, int> ht;
ht[hash_wrapper] = val;
```

Comment: How about the fact that it has undefined behavior as a result of violating the strict aliasing rule?  That could be addressed by writing `char`s into the string instead of trying to force in `int`s.  Or by using `std::memcpy()` instead of assignment through a pointer.

Comment: while it can be made to work, the hashing algorithm for std::string is highly likely optimized for strings so it may be very bad when using for arbitrary data, resulting in lots of hash collisions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code violates strict aliasing.

Your code is extremely unclear what it is doing.

The point of hash maps is that they are maps.  Your hash map goes from an obscurely transformed string type to your data, not from a reasonable key to your data.

My advice is:

1. Write a hash combiner, or use one that someone else has published (with proper attribution/rights) like boost's.  A hash combiner takes two hashes and makes one out of them.
2. Extend to hash combiners that take an arbitrary sequence of hashes and combines them.

Now write a short library.

```
namespace MyHash {
  // by default, dispatch to std::hash:
  template<class T>
  std::size_t runtime_hash( T const& t ) {
    return std::hash<T>{}(t);
  }
  // range-like support (begin/end):
  template<class R>
  std::size_t hash_range( R const& r );
  // tuple-like support (std::get, etc):
  template<std::size_t...Is, class T>
  std::size_t tuple_hasher( std::index_sequence<Is...>, T const& t );

  // TODO: supply this function
  inline std::size_t hash_combine( std::size_t lhs, std::size_r rhs ) {
    // write this
  }
  // support for 0 to infinite args:
  inline std::size_t hash_combine( std::size_t x ) {
    return x;
  }
  inline std::size_t hash_combine() {
    return 0;
  }
  template<class...Ts>
  std::size_t hash_combine( std::size_t lhs, std::size_t rhs, Ts... ts ) {
    return hash_combine( lhs, hash_combine( rhs, ts... ) );
  }

  // Add std runtime_hashs here:

  // std "range" type supports:
  template<class...Ts>
  std::size_t runtime_hash( std::vector<Ts...> const& v ) {
    return hash_range(v);
  }
  template<class...Ts>
  std::size_t runtime_hash( std::set<Ts...> const& s ) {
    return hash_range(s);
  }
  template<class...Ts>
  std::size_t runtime_hash( std::unordered_set<Ts...> const& s ) {
    return hash_range(s);
  }
  template<class...Ts>
  std::size_t runtime_hash( std::map<Ts...> const& m ) {
    return hash_range(m);
  }
  template<class...Ts>
  std::size_t runtime_hash( std::unordered_map<Ts...> const& m ) {
    return hash_range(m);
  }

  // tuple-like support:
  template<class...Ts>
  std::size_t runtime_hash( std::tuple<Ts...> const& t ) {
    return tuple_hasher( std::make_index_sequence<Ts...>{}, t );
  }
  template<class T0, class T1>
  std::size_t runtime_hash( std::pair<T0, T1> const& t ) {
    return tuple_hasher( std::make_index_sequence<2>{}, t );
  }
  template<class T, std::size_t N>
  std::size_t runtime_hash( std::array<T, N> const& t ) {
    return tuple_hasher( std::make_index_sequence<N>{}, t );
  }

  // optional.  Note that hash of an engaged optional is distinct
  // from a hash of a value by a hash_combine.  An optional acts
  // as a range of 0 or 1 element hash-wise.
  template<class T>
  std::size_t runtime_hash( std::optional<T> const& t ) {
    std::size_t retval = 0x0;
    if (t) retval = hash_combine(retval, runtime_hash(t) );
    return retval;
  }
  // add more types here!

  struct runtime_hasher {
    template<class T>
    std::size_t operator()(T const& t)const{
      return runtime_hash(t);
    }
  };
  
  template<class R>
  std::size_t hash_range( R const& r ) {
    std::size_t seed = 0;
    for (auto const& e : r) {
      seed = hash_combine( seed, runtime_hash(r) );
    }
  }
  template<std::size_t...Is, class T>
  std::size_t tuple_hasher( std::index_sequence<Is...>, T const& t ) {
    return hash_combine( runtime_hash(std::get<Is>(t))... );
  }
}
```

now, whenever you need a custom runtime hash, override `runtime_hash` for your custom type in the namespace of the type.

With this work,

```
namespace bob {
  struct alice {
    int val1, val2, val3, val4;
    friend auto operator==(const alice&, const alice&) = default;
  };
}
```

I can add hash support:

```
namespace bob {
  inline std::size_t runtime_hash( alice const& a ) {
    return runtime_hash( std::tie(a.val1, a.val2, a.val3, a.val4) );
  }
}
```

and with that

```
std::unordered_map<bob::alice, int, MyHash::runtime_hasher> map;
```

just works.

The `runtime_hash` function is found via ADL.  What more, `std::vector<bob::alice>` has hash support, as does `std::tuple<bob::alice>` and `std::tuple<std::set<bob::alice>, bob::alice>`, etc.  And if you write any other composite type and give it support like I did the `std` containers, those containing `bob::alice` will also work.

The size and complexity of this utility code above is short enough that messing around with buffers and pointers and undefined aliasing is definitely not worth it.

Note that I'm naming this `runtime_hash` -- this both makes it somewhat uniquely named (important for ADL), and highlights that no guarantee whatsoever is made that this hash is stable over different executions of the program.  You cannot rely on `std` hash's being stable in such a way, as they do not provide that guarantee.

Apologies for any typos.  The above code was typed directly into the answer, and has never been compiled, so it probably contains at least one tpyo.